# Angular httpClient object access via string literals is disallowed

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http

error is in for loop in my component. It say that data isn't iterable, but it's an array. How can I fix it;
I was trying to do something like

```
this.httpService.getUser().subscribe((data: Task[]) => this.task = data);
```

but it says :

> error: object access via string literals is disallowed

I have an interface

*Task.ts*

```
export interface Task {
  taskCategory: string;
  taskTitle: string;
  taskDescription: string;
  taskCompleted: boolean;
}
```

I have a *task.json*

```
{
  "todoList": [
    {
      "taskCategory": "frontend",
      "taskTitle": "fix a bug",
      "taskDescription": "we have a bug with drag and drop in todo table, fix it",
      "taskCompleted": false
    },
    {
      "taskCategory": "back-end",
      "taskTitle": "send data",
      "taskDescription": "send data from back-end",
      "taskCompleted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

My *http.service.ts* is :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}
)
export class HttpService {
  #url = '/assets/task.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<Task[]> {


    return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.#url);
  }
}
```

and a component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'http';
  task: Task[] = [];
 
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }
  user: User[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
   
    this.httpService.getUser().subscribe((data: Task[]) => {
      for (let item of data) {
        this.task = [{
          taskCategory: item.taskCategory,
          taskCompleted: item.taskCompleted,
          taskDescription: item.taskDescription,
          taskTitle: item.taskTitle
        }]
      }
    });
  }


}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of task; index as i">
  {{item.taskCategory}}
</div>
```

Comment: Try with `return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.#url).pipe(pluck('todoList'));`

Comment: it help's. Ty a lot; But I doing it by example on youtube. And there it works. But that was ng 6 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous versions of Angular, you had to transform the received response to JSON by doing :

```
http.get(url)
    .map( res => res.json() )
    .subscribe( data => ... )
```

In newer versions (Angular 8+, I believe) you have to observe the response's data if you want only it :

```
http.get(url, { observe : "response" })
    .subscribe( data => ... )
```